# Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat

Sometimes I am getting the following error in Tomcat 7  while calling a third-party service through `HttpURLConnection` object.

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    com.myapp.QueryAPI.SearchDealerTxn.execute(SearchDealerTxn.java:106)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

After restarting Tomcat, the issue got resolved.
Any Idea? please share.

Comment: How is authentication being done? 403 means that either the server (Tomcat) or the application don't like your credentials.

Comment: There is no credentials  required. Application is hosted in the server having direct internet connection .No proxy.

Comment: Umm.... your question has the word *Proxy" right in it. Looks like there is a proxy to me.